# Keycloak fails to load provider classes when using Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Trying to follow along with [this article getting Keycloak embedded in Spring Boot application](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app), but using Gradle instead of Maven. When I clone the repo and use `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage` it works fine. However, when I use the Spring Boot plugin for Gradle, things get mixed up with the following exception excerpts when starting:

```
RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider from jar:file:<...hidden...>!/BOOT-INF/lib/resteasy-jackson2-provider-4.5.3.Final.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
```

And it's the same for JAXBXmlSeeAlsoProvider, JAXBXmlRootElementProvider, etc.

My understanding from the article is that rather than try to provide all these deps, a custom implementation is used, via ServiceLoader interface, by the files located in `META-INF/services/`. However, when I compare the jars produced by Maven and Gradle, they are different.

Here's a snippet of folder contents for Maven build

```
/
- META-INF/
-- MANIFEST.MF
-- services/
-- other stuff from src/main/resources/
- BOOT-INF/
-- Spring Boot stuff...
```

And from Gradle...

```
/
- META-INF/
-- MANIFEST.MF
- BOOT-INF/
-- classes/
--- META-INF/
---- services/
---- other stuff from src/main/resources/
```

I'm guessing that's the reason why it's failing... I've tried replacing the services folder with a `spring.factories` file, manipulating the `bootJar` config to place the `services/` directory in the root META-INF instead of the one in `BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF`, but no luck.

Is it just a Gradle thing? Would it be better just to explicitely define those deps?

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. It appears broken due to Spring Boot version 2.3, rather than any of the above.